# File fails to upload when using xety/cake3-upload plugin

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.1, cakephp-3.x

I am not able to upload a file from one folder to another in CakePHP. Here is my code.

First I loaded the plugin and added this code in `ProductsTable.php`

```
$this->addBehavior('Xety/Cake3Upload.Upload', [
    'fields' => [
        'productimg_file' => [
            'path' => 'uploads/avatar/:id/:md5'
        ]
    ]
]);
```

then I added in my `add.cpt`

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('productcode');
    echo $this->Form->input('productname');
    echo $this->Form->input('productprice');
    echo $this->Form->input('quantity');
    echo $this->Form->input('productdesc');
    echo $this->Form->input('productimg_file',['type' => 'file']);
?>
```

Still the file doesn't get moved to the `webroot` dir.

```
public function add() {
    $product = $this->Products->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $product = $this->Products->patchEntity($product, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Products->save($product)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The product has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('The product could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('product'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['product']);
}
```

Comment: Is it throwing any errors? Please edit you question and add your `ProductsController::add()` action and any other relevant code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have uploaded successfully by that plugin. At beginning, I was your error but I fixed it. Here my steps...

Within: CakePHP 3.2 Red Velvet

1. Download source
   Copy **UploadBehavior.php**
   to */src/Model/Behavior*
2. Copy `"xety/cake3-upload": "1.*"` (with the double quote "") paste to /config/bootstrap.php in the "require-dev": {...},

Ex:

```
"require-dev": {
        "psy/psysh": "@stable",
        "cakephp/debug_kit": "~3.2",
        "cakephp/bake": "~1.1",
        "xety/cake3-upload": "1.*"
    },
```

3. open terminal (window cmd) type:

   composer update

Note: if you don't have composer, google and install it.

=> I knew number 1 and 2 are same, but I made it for sure.

4. Config as plugin manual.
   This below config was in **Model/Table/model_nameTable.php** NOT **Model/Entity/model.php**

Ex:

```
$this->addBehavior('Xety/Cake3Upload.Upload', [
        'fields' => [
            'avatar' => [
                'path' => '/img/avatars/:id/:md5'
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        );
```

5. Set the update URL with

   '/img/folder_name/:id/:md5'

Ex:

```
'/img/avatars/:id/:md5'
```

6. Make sure the FORM in view is define as:

   $this->Form->create($user, ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'])

and input file was correct name:

```
$this->Form->file('fieldname_file');
```

Ex:

```
$this->Form->file('avatar_file');
```

Not need to call anything from controller, when you submit form, it will uploaded automatically.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Your view seems to be incomplete. There is no `$this->Form->create()`.

The [plugin instructions](https://github.com/Xety/Cake3-Upload) mentions that you you have to set your form to accept files:

```
$this->Form->create($foo, ['type'=>'file']);
// .. or ..
$this->Form->create($foo, ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']);
```

Uploads are stored by default under `/app/webroot/img/`. Make sure this folder is writable by Apache or Nginx.

Comment: yes there is  $this->Form->create its just i have not put it here..and also my app folder have all permissions

Answer (score 0):

_file is a default suffix which you will use only in .ctp file. Not in model.
Change your behavior in model. Hope this will help.

```
$this->addBehavior('Xety/Cake3Upload.Upload', [
    'fields' => [
        'productimg' => [
            'path' => 'uploads/avatar/:id/:md5'
        ]
    ]
]);
```